# Trouble with some basic jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Having trouble in some jQuery task.
Below are the example for the script.

```js
$('.filter-item').each(function() {
  var catID = $(this).data('category');
  return $(".filter-item span").wrap('<a href=#' + catID + '></a>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filters-list">
  <div class="filter-item" data-category="1">
    <span>category 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="filter-item" data-category="2">
    <span>category 2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="filter-item" data-category="3">
    <span>category 3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you guys can see the result I'm getting from the script are as below.

```
<div class="filter-item" data-category="1">
   <a href="#1">
      <a href="#2">
         <a href="#3">
            <span>category 1</span>
         </a>
      </a>
   </a>
</div>
<div class="filter-item" data-category="2">
   <a href="#1">
      <a href="#2">
         <a href="#3">
            <span>category 2</span>
         </a>
      </a>
   </a>
</div> 
<div class="filter-item" data-category="3">
   <a href="#1">
      <a href="#2">
         <a href="#3">
            <span>category 3</span>
         </a>
      </a>
   </a>
</div>
```

What am I trying to achieve is like below.

```
<div class="filter-item" data-category="1">
   <a href="#1">
      <span>category 1</span>
   </a>
</div>
<div class="filter-item" data-category="2">
   <a href="#2">
      <span>category 2</span>
   </a>
</div>
<div class="filter-item" data-category="3">
   <a href="#3">
      <span>category 3</span>
   </a>
</div>
```

Hope that's clear.
Sorry I'm not good at jQuery, and hopefully there is someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're wrapping all the `span`s in `a` tag, but essentially you want to wrap the inner `span` only. For that, you should use `$(this).find("span")` and wrap the found element only, instead of all the `span`s under `.filter-item`s.

Also, you don't need to return anything from the function since you're modifying the elements in-place.

```js
$('.filter-item').each(function() {
  var catID = $(this).data('category');
  $(this).find("span").wrap('<a href=#' + catID + '></a>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filters-list">
  <div class="filter-item" data-category="1">
    <span>category 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="filter-item" data-category="2">
    <span>category 2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="filter-item" data-category="3">
    <span>category 3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```